# How to use explode for a struct type in Scala

Tags: xml, scala, function, apache-spark, databricks

I have read some data from a XML file using struct type like this:

```
<CATALOG>
    <TABLE at_name="Furniture">
        <ROWDATA>
            <ROW typeid="0" caseid="0" key="1" code="0"/>
            <ROW typeid="1" caseid="0" key="1" code="0"/>
            <ROW typeid="1" caseid="1" key="1" code="0"/>
        </ROWDATA>
    </TABLE>
<CATALOG>
```

Code to read XML:

```
val furntitureDF = session.read
  .option("rootTag", "CATALOG")
  .option("rowTag", "TABLE")
  .schema(getFurnitureSchema)
  .xml(filePath)
  .filter("at_name = 'Furniture'")



   def getFurnitureSchema: StructType = {

     val rowType = new StructType()
       .add("_typeid", StringType)
       .add("_caseid", StringType)
       .add("_key", StringType)
       .add("_code", StringType)
  

     val rowDataType = new StructType()
       .add("ROW", ArrayType(rowType))

     val FurnitureTableType = new StructType()
       .add("at_name", StringType)
       .add("ROWDATA", rowDataType)

     FurnitureTableType
   }
```

Output I get:

| _name | ROWDATA |
| --- | --- |
| First | {[{0, 0, 1, 0 },{1, 0, 1, 0 },{1, 1, 1, 0 }]} |

I am getting some extra brackets as shown above so even if I use the explode function it does not work. The expected output is:

| _name | ROWDATA | rowid |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First | {0, 0, 1, 0 } | 1 |
| First | {1, 0, 1, 0 } | 2 |
| First | {1, 1, 1, 0 } | 3 |

Any ideas on how I can get this result?

Comment: add sample xml data ?

Comment: Please see my edit

Comment: why are you creating `getFurnitureSchema` schema ?

Comment: I used that because the XML is quite big with many table tags and the columns are different for each attribute name(at_name)

Answer (score 0):

explode only does the converting(exploding) array Items into individual items in your Array items which does in your output.

```
Input - Array<Struct>
Output - Struct (exploded to multiple rows)
```

now you have to pull the elements out of each struct item.

this would be like

```
explodedDF.select("`_name`","`ROWDATA`.`_typeid`","`ROWDATA`.`_caseid`",`ROWDATA`.`_key`,`ROWDATA`.`_code`)
```

Comment: Explode for me is not working. If I try exploding it is still returning the same dataframe in one row.